# Maven assembly.xml is not reading from Eclipse

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to build tar file using maven assembly plugin and below is the code snippet for the same.  When I am doing build from CMD prompt using mvn install command then tar is generating whereas it is not working from eclipse and getting the below logs.  Note:- Maven and JDK is common for both the execution.

pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <tarLongFileMode>gnu</tarLongFileMode>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>                           
                        <goal>attached</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Eclipse console

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:attached (default) @ test ---
[INFO] Assemblies have been skipped per configuration of the skipAssembly parameter.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- test-assembly-verifier:1.4:verify (default) @ test ---
[INFO] Skipping assembly verification.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ test ---
[INFO] Skipping artifact installation
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

CMD console

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:attached (default) @ test   ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: assembly.xml
```

Comment: I can only speculate that you are running Maven from Eclipse with a launcher which contains some parameters which turn off that. Apart from that without a full pom file it's hard to see what is happening there. Furthermore I don't know that kind of plugin `test-assembly-verifier` is running there and which purpose that has? Apart from that those plugin versions a little bit out of date....BTW: The title of this post is misleading cause the problem is that something is skipped while being executed through eclipse but the descriptor is read correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks maven-assembly-plugin goal [assembly:single] can only be run from command line.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-assembly-plugin-2.5.5/attached-mojo.html

If any solution will be available, please advise.